# unity raycast hit calls three times when item dropped to the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, game-development

My raycast from a ball to ground calls three times on every touch to ground.

I need only one time and toptup animation.
call is this:

```
  private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceground + 0.1f))
        {
            Debug.Log("intheair");

        }
        else {
            dropped = true;
            Debug.Log("dropped");
            if (dropped && !GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("topup"))
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("topup");
                Debug.Log("trigged");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue.

```
        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceground + 0.1f) && !dropped)
    {
        Debug.Log("intheair");

    }
    else {
        dropped = true;
        Debug.Log("dropped");
        if (dropped && !GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("topup"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("topup");
            Debug.Log("trigged");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why its touching 3 three times at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Once your object is within

`distanceground + 0.1f`

Then

`if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceground + 0.1f))`

Will return `false` every `FixedUpdate()` and defer to your `else` block, so the issue is not with the `Raycast`.

The issue ***most likely*** lies within the fact that you're checking `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0)` in `FixedUpdate()`. At lower framerates, `FixedUpdate()` can be called several times for every `Update()`, causing

`if (dropped && !GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("topup"))`

to evaluate `true` because the visual animation state may not have had time to update yet.

I would recommend moving it all into `Update()`.